# standalone testrunner, that runs as a windows application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-code

So test runners seem to come in 2 forms, they either integrate into the IDE, like visual studio, or they are triggered by "dotnet test", and are intended to be run in CI/CD environment.

I could do with a test runner that ran as a standalone windows application, I can of course write such a thing but, is there some way of running xunit or nunit test explorer etc outside the IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be a GUI test runner for NUnit. It was apparently removed from the project. The developement is now done as a separate project: https://github.com/TestCentric/testcentric-gui

Comment: ah right...that looks believable...let me take a look